# Parse specific text from CSV rows into a new column using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, parsing

I have a csv file that has the block of text in a field that I would like to extract to a new column. For example my csv looks like this below:

`house, paint, status-text
 house1, green, this house is nice it gets a status of result: PASS this is good
 house2, red, this house is not too nice it gets a status of result: FAIL this is bad
 house3, blue, this house is the best it gets a status of result: PASS this is great,`

I would like to run a simple regex to pull out the (result: PASS) or (result: FAIL) into a new column so the CSV would now look like below:

`house, paint, status-text, status
 house1, green, this house is nice it gets a status of result: PASS this is good, PASS
 house2, red, this house is not too nice it gets a status of result: FAIL this is bad, FAIL 
 house3, blue, this house is the best it gets a status of result: PASS this is great, PASS`

I was thinking of using a Pandas data frame but not sure how to parse out the (PASS/FAIL) and move it to its own column for the 3 rows, and potentially having this scale to hundreds of rows. Any example of how to do this as a small sample would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can load the csv to pandas dataframe and then do this

```
    conditions = [
        df["status-text"].str.contains("result: PASS "),
        df["status-text"].str.contains("result: FAIL "),
    ]

    choices = ["PASS", "FAIL"]

    df["status"] = numpy.select(conditions, choices, default=None)

    print(df)
```

Comment: Wow this was a great, easy to understand and elegant solution. I was able to integrate it into my poc. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where`

```py
df['status'] = np.where(df["status-text"].str.contains('PASS'), 'PASS', 'FAIL')
df
    house   paint                                        status-text status
0  house1   green   this house is nice it gets a status of result...   PASS
1  house2     red   this house is not too nice it gets a status o...   FAIL
2  house3    blue   this house is the best it gets a status of re...   PASS
```